# EventLogInstaller and Installutil on Windows server 2008

Tags: .net

Im using the trick to create the source and custom event logs on my machine but when I run it on windows server 2008 I get a log not found error when running the installutil.exe command. Of course its not found as I want it to be created!!
Any ideas? I'm running the commands as Administrator
sorry this is the trick http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;329291
Im trying to use the second approach, but with the following

```
myEventLogInstaller.Log = "CustomApp";
```

Comment: "Trick".  Maybe that's your problem...  But, without detail, how can anyone possibly offer any help?

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: Are you running InstallUtil from a command prompt running as Adminstrator?

Comment: yes am right clicking cmd.exe and selecting run as admin then executing the command